# Stayed outside USA for 2 months: Does that reduce the taxes?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, turbotax

I have lived in USA for over five years now and hence I am now counted as resident for tax purposes. Previously I used Glacier tax software which used to ask me how many days of the year I stayed outside US and provide tax rebate for that (I think). This year, I tried turbotax and H&R, but both don't ask how many days I stayed outside. Is it usual? Will I get a rebate for the days I was not in US.

Comment: Could Glacier have been checking how long you were ***in*** the US, to ensure that you were a resident?

Comment: I don't remember it, but it may be true. Glacier was provided by my university.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither TurboTax nor H&R Block are intended for Non-Resident filers. You should continue using GLACIER if you have access to it, or talk to a professional tax preparer (EA/CPA licensed in your State or a properly accredited tax preparer) who's experienced with foreigners filing NR returns.

Knowing how many days you were in or out of the country is not enough, your immigration status matters, and also your citizenship. During the first 5 years, most students are considered non-residents if they're in F1/J1 status and the days of their presence while in that status don't count. For citizens of some countries, this period is not limited, due to the tax treaty, and the days of their presence don't count even after the 5 years, as long as they're in J1/F1 status.

If you *are* considered resident in the US for the whole year - you do not get any "rebate" for the days you were out of country.

Comment: Thanks. Seeking further clarification: I was not a resident for the entire year, since 5 years got completed in July. Also, medicare and social security were deducted from my salary after July. I am on F1 OPT. So, do you think, I would get a tax rebate.

Comment: @user984260 How on Earth would I know?